# Can I write for .Net 4 using VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0

Can I write code against .Net 4 and its libraries using VS2008? If so how should I configure it?

I realise that VS2008 will probably struggle with language changes such as the *dynamic* keyword but can I install the version 4 and target it anyway? My only real interest is in being able to use some of the new libraries, in particular I'm interested in the TPL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im afraid not :( its 2010 or nothing, it will run backwards but not forwards. So 2010 will run all prior versions of the framework but not vice versa.

My only suggestion is  [2010 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/)

Comment: Not quite "all prior version": VS2010 will not target 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: @Richard - Good thing no one cares about those versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the **Parallel Extensions** in Visual Studio 2008, they are still available for .NET 3.5 in the **Reactive Framework**, which can be downloaded here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could use Visual Studio to write your code and use the 4.0 compiler with the command prompt to compile against .Net 4.0. It would be similar to using Notepad++ or other code writing software.

That way, you can still use the Intellisense. But you will have to deal with errors and you won't be able to run or debug using Visual Studio.

But, its would be a real PITA. I suggest that you get the [Express Edition of 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You can always try SharpDevelop 4 (beta).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that but you can get fully fledged version of VS 2010 (and also SQL 2008) if you become a participant in Website Spark program of Microsoft. The conditions are quite good for individual developers with no capital and no company. Look here:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/